# Get data from JSON with Angular2 Promise

Tags: json, http, angular, angular-promise, angular2-services

I'm trying to get data from a JSON file following the [http tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) from the Angular2 documentation:

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Hero } from './hero';

private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: // some template,
  styles: // some style,
  providers: [HeroService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => {
        this.heroes = heroes;
        console.log('heroes', this.heroes);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public power: string,
    public alterEgo?: string
  ) {  }
}
```

I replaced `private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';` with my endpoint that is a JSON file (`private heroesUrl = 'app/mockups/heroes.json';`), that contains data according to `hero` model.

But when i run my app i get no data and there is any error message.
Isn't my code correct?

Comment: Where do you not get data? Can you please add a `console.log(data);` in the code in your question where you expect `data` (or whatever name) you expect to have a value?

Comment: Where can i add `console.log(data)`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where do you expect what variable to have a value? To debug it you can add a `console.log(...)` line. This allows you to investigate yourself and allows us to see what you expect. I can't answer your question when I don't know what you expect to happen.

Comment: I expect to have data in `heroes` variable. How to add `console.log(data)` in `getHeroes()` function?

Comment: I updated your question. Is that where you want the value?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I get `undefined`.

Comment: What do you get when you return `.data` from `response.json().data`?

Comment: I don't know. Do you know any way to add a `console.log` there?

Comment: Keep `console.log()` where it is and just remove `.data`.

Comment: It fails on `*NgFor` that i use in the template file for cycling on JSON elements. `EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/components/app.component.js class AppComponent - inline template:0:285 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: What does `console.log()` print?

Comment: It prints what i pasted above. It prints even the following error: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: That's an error caused by `*ngFor` not the output of `console.log()`. The output of `console.log()` should have been printed before the error you posted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That error has been printed after the `console.log()` output. Anyway the output is `undefined`.

Comment: If the output is still undefined than this means that the response from the server didn't contain any data. Actually I don't believe it is undefined. If `*ngFor` complains about an object, than it didn't get `undefined`. Also `[object Object]` in the error message indicates that it got an object (!= `undefined`)

Comment: I solved. The problem was that the JSON object must start with a property that has the same name of `response.json().data`. So i renamed the first property to `data`. Please upvote this comment so other members can see it.

Comment: Is there 'data' field in your json file? Try using angular filter {{Hero | json}} wherever you are trying to access Hero object in your html, just to check if it has data.

Comment: @smartmouse your comment helped me a lot. Why don't you answer the question?

Comment: @Vincenzo Done, thank you! So, now you can upvote it :D

Answer (score 3):

The solution is that the JSON object must start with a property that has the same name of `response.json().data`.

Renaming the first property to `data` does the job.